# php autoload searches for invalid path

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, php-mongodb

We encounter a very strange error after deploying our application to production.

It seems like a typo in package name (Docsrine vs Doctrine) and it's not always the same package that seems to be broken. The correct version of the file mentioned in the error exists at the correct path (the one with Doctrine).

The cases we found only present in doctrine/mongo stuff.
We experience this with php 7.0.13 and 7.2.5. pecl-mongodb versions 1.2.10 and 1.4.3.

A restart of the fpm seems to resolve the problem (no
te that we also do a restart immediately after deploy, but with no success).

> 2018/05/07 18:35:15 [error] 4749#4749: *85488813 FastCGI sent in
>   stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Uncaught ErrorException: Warning:
>   require(/var/www/my_app/releases/20180507153309/vendor/composer/../doctrine/mongodb/lib/Docsrine/MongoDB/Iterator.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in file
>   /var/www/my_app/releases/20180507153309/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/ApcClassLoader.php:112
>   in
>   /var/www/rec/releases/20180507153309/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/ApcClassLoader.php:112

Have anyone else encountered similar issues?

Comment: Are you using something like vagrant and macosx as OS?

Comment: Have you tried to run `composer dump-autoloader -o` yet? If not then do it and tell us if that fixes your issue

Comment: @DonCallisto: No. Centos 7.3

Comment: @ReynierPM: we disabled autoload optimize as it provided a performance boost(large applications with a lot of clases involved).

Comment: @Alexandru you could run it without the `-o` and it should do the same, have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

We have taken a number of steps that solved the issue (we haven't encountered it in a week now).
1. Remove unused php modules - couchbase2, gd, amqp
2. Upgrade the version of igbinary module.